# When talking about a person can I always replace "that" or "who" with "whom"?

Tags: relative-clauses

When talking on a person can I always replace the relative clause "that" with "whom"? I am pretty confused with the using of "whom".

For example:

> 1) The teacher **that** *(also who)* was here - now is there. > The teacher **whom** was here - now is there.

Example No.2

> 2) The waiter **who** gave you the food - is in the kitchen now. > The waiter **whom** gave you the food - is in the kitchen now.

example No.3

> 3) Those guys **who** you talked to, now are looking for you. > Those
>   guys **whom** you talked to, now are looking for you.

Comment: You'd be better off coming at this from the *opposite* direction. For all practical purposes, you should probably assume you can always replace ***whom*** with ***who***, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Except for No. 3, no, you can't. Moreover, you shouldn't.

**Whom** is a pronoun for the objective or prepositional case in English.

> For Whom The Bell Tolls [title]
>
> She is a teacher whom we all love.

But it's fine to say

> Those guys whom you talked to are looking for you now.

Never use *whom* where the nominative case would be indicated.

> The waiter <strike>whom</strike> who gave you the food is in the kitchen now

An easy way to remember this is to use *whom* where you would use *him* or *her*.

> She is a great teacher. We all love her -> She is a great teacher whom we all love.

Final note: *whom* is fading from English. Outside of academic or formal works, you rarely hear it.

Where it would be formally correct to say

> Whom did you give the book to?

or

> To whom did you give the book?

in conversation almost everyone will say

> Who did you give the book to?

or

> Who'd you give the book to?

(But I personally would still feel awkward saying "To **who** did you give the book?")

Now, do you see why No. 3 works and the others don't?

Comment: I think "you'd **never** say" is a bit strong there. It's quite true that in ordinary conversation most of us would ask *Who did you give it **to**?*, so probably those who don't like the preposition coming at the end will include a higher proportion of "pedants" (to whom the ***who / whom*** distinction remains important) than the population at large. But hundreds of people have written [*To who did you give...?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22To+who+did+you+give%22) Never say never, I always say.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: A fair point. I've modified my stance now.

Comment: I totally endorse your point about ***whom** is fading from English*, though. In fact, I think the specific phrase ***To whom** it may concern...* is perhaps the only one left where *everyone* would agree we need to keep that /m/. Arguably that entire phrase is becoming something of a "fixed form", but I reckon it probably reinforces the tendency to go for ***to whom*** over ***to who*** in other contexts (i.e. - many of us are much more likely to be "fussy" when the explicitly-specified preposition ***to*** precedes ***who[m]***).

Answer (score 0):

1. The teacher whom was here is there now
2. The waiter whom gave you the food is in the kitchen now.
3. Those guys whom you talked to are now looking for you.

When that/who is used as the subject of a clause, you cannot replace it with the objective form of who i.e. whom.

So your sentences #1 and #2 are ungrammatical.

On the other hand, sentence #3, though the use of whom is formal and less common, is grammatical. However, it'll be  appropriate if you  use the preposition 'to' in front of whom as follows:

Those guys with/to whom you talked are now looking for you.

However, the use of who in place of the objective form whom  in most cases is very common and idiomatic both in formal and informal English.

Comment: In sentence #3, I would use ' to whom you spoke', not talked.  I need to spend time I don't have right now figuring out why, but I'm not comfortable with the to in 'talked to' being shifted in front of who or whom.